# How would I concat and group similar values in an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object

```js
const array = [
   {keyA: "HG 386893", count: 1, type: "dha"},
   {keyA: "AL 386893", count: 1, type: "gop"},
   {keyA: "HG 386893", count: 2, type: "ind"},
   {keyA: "NC 386893", count: 1, type: "dha"},
   {keyA: "HG 386893", count: 1, type: "gop"},
   {keyA: "RO 386893", count: 1, type: "ind"}
];
```

I want to merge keys based on similar `keyA` property and concat `type` and add `count`. So final result will be:

```js
const result = [
   {keyA: "HG 386893", count: 4, type: "dha,ind,gop"},
   {keyA: "AL 386893", count: 1, type: "gop"},
   {keyA: "NC 386893", count: 1, type: "dha"},
   {keyA: "RO 386893", count: 1, type: "ind"}
];
```

The way I am implementing this is:

1. sort the array on `keyA`
2. loop through sorted array & if previous value = current value, add `count` and concat `type`

I know this is not an optimal solution, so I need some help to optimize this in better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const array = [
  { keyA: "HG 386893", count: 1, type: "dha" },
  { keyA: "AL 386893", count: 1, type: "gop" },
  { keyA: "HG 386893", count: 2, type: "ind" },
  { keyA: "NC 386893", count: 1, type: "dha" },
  { keyA: "HG 386893", count: 1, type: "gop" },
  { keyA: "RO 386893", count: 1, type: "ind" }
];

const grouped = Object.values(array.reduce((acc,item) => {
  const { keyA, count, type } = item;
  const prev = acc[keyA];
  acc[keyA] = prev 
    ? { ...item, count: prev.count+count, type: `${prev.type},${type}` } 
    : item;
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)** for O(n) time complexity:

```js
const array = [
   {keyA: "HG 386893", count: 1, type: "dha"},
   {keyA: "AL 386893", count: 1, type: "gop"},
   {keyA: "HG 386893", count: 2, type: "ind"},
   {keyA: "NC 386893", count: 1, type: "dha"},
   {keyA: "HG 386893", count: 1, type: "gop"},
   {keyA: "RO 386893", count: 1, type: "ind"}
];
//console.log(array);

const groupedByKeyA = new Map();
for (const obj of array) {
    if (groupedByKeyA.has(obj.keyA)) {
        const currentType = groupedByKeyA.get(obj.keyA).type;
        groupedByKeyA.get(obj.keyA).type = `${currentType},${obj.type}`
    } else {
        groupedByKeyA.set(obj.keyA, obj);
    }
}
//console.log(groupedByKeyA);

const groupedArray = Array.from(groupedByKeyA.values());
console.log(groupedArray);
```